# $\|D_{f}(x) v\|=\|v\|$ $\implies$ $f$ is an isometry

Tags: analysis

Let $f\colon \mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}^m$ be a $C^2$ map such that $\|D_f(x)v\|=\|v\|$ for all $v\in\mathbb{R}^m$, where $D_f(x)$ is the derivative of $f$ at $x$. Then I am asked to prove that $\|f(x)-f(y)\|=\|x-y\|$ for all $x,y\in\mathbb{R}^m$. There's a hint that says to use the Schwarz theorem.

I just can prove that $\|f(x)-f(y)\| \le \|x-y\|$, using the image of $\alpha \colon [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}^m$, $\alpha(t)=x+(y-x)t$.

Consider $\gamma\colon [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}^m$, $\gamma(t)=f(\alpha(t))$, we have that $\gamma '(t)=D_{f}(x +(y-x)t).(y-x)$. Since $\gamma$ connect $f(x)$ and $f(y)$ and it is $C^{1}$ we have:

$\|f(x)-f(y)\| \leq L(\gamma) = \displaystyle\int_{[0,1]} \|\gamma '(t)\|dt=\displaystyle\int_{[0,1]}\|D_{f}(x +(y-x)t).(y-x)\|dt$.
By assumtion this is equals to $\displaystyle\int_{[0,1]} \|x-y\| \leq \|\displaystyle\int_{[0,1]} x-y\space dt\|= \|x-y\|$.

I have no idea how use schwarz theorem in this case.

Any help is welcome.

Comment: showing the second derivatives vanish ?

Comment: I don't know how to prove it, and how it follows

Comment: what is $v$? fixed or variable? what does $D_f(x)\cdot v$ mean? presumably $D_f(x)$ is the derivative of $f$ at $x\in\text{dom}(f)$, which is represented by an $m\times m$ matrix. then the dot product $D_f(x)\cdot v$ does not make sense, so do you mean matrix multiplication?

Comment: @symplectomorphic yes he meant multiplication of a matrix $D_f(x)$ with a vector $v$

Comment: @Oddone Can you add your work for showing that $f$ is a contraction?

Comment: @CameronWilliams: $\|f(x)-f(y)\|\leq\|y-x\|$ does not make $f$ a contraction. for that you need $k\color{blue}{<1}$ such that $\|f(x)-f(y)\|\leq k\|y-x\|$.

Comment: @CameronWilliams ready

Comment: I consider the case $k=1$ a contraction because I don't know what else to call it in that case :P

Comment: @CameronWilliams: The condition $\lVert f(x)-f(y)\rVert\leq \lVert x-y\rVert$ is probably best described by saying that $f$ is [Lipschitz continuous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lipschitz_continuity) with constant $1,$ in which case the function $f$ may be referred to as a [metric map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_map).

Comment: @WillR Ohh good point!

Comment: [This](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/220570/sufficient-condition-for-isometry?rq=1) can be helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$f$ is an isometry if its second partials vanish.  Here's a quick explanation why: If the second partials vanish, then $D_f(\cdot)$ is constant, so that 
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
\forall(v\in\mathbb{R}^m) \: f(v) & = & f(0) + \int_0^1 \frac{d}{dt} f(tv)\: dt \\
& =&  f(0) + \int_0^1 D_f(x) \cdot v \:dt \\
& = & f(0) + \int_0^1 D_f(0) \cdot v \:dt \\
& = & f(0) + D_f(0)\cdot v.
\end{eqnarray}
$$
Then $\forall(v,w \in \mathbb{R}^m) \: ||f(v)-f(w)|| = ||D_f(0)v - D_f(0)w|| = ||D_f(0) (v-w)|| = ||v-w||$, as desired.  The more interesting part is showing that the second partials all vanish:

Some notation: Let $f^i$ be component $i$ of $f$ (so $f=(f^1,f^2,\dots,f^m)^T$); let $f^i_j := \partial_j f^i$ be the partial of $f^i$ in direction $e_j$; and let $f_j := \partial_j f = (f^1_j,f^2_j,\dots,f^m_j)^T$.

$||D_f(x) v|| = ||v||$ for all $v$ means that $||D_f(x)||$ is an orthogonal matrix.  So $D_f(x)^T D_f(x) =D_f(x) D_f(x)^T = \mathcal{I}_{m\times m}$, or in components $\sum_j f^i_j f^k_j = \delta^{ik}$ and $\sum_if^i_j f^i_k = \delta_{jk} = f_j \cdot f_k$.  Apply a partial derivative to the second of these relations to get $0 = \partial_l (f_j \cdot f_k) = f_{jl} \cdot f_k + f_j \cdot f_{kl}$, so that $f_{jl} \cdot f_k = -f_j \cdot f_{kl}$, which holds for all indices $j,k,l$.  Now we have
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
f_{jl} \cdot f_k  & = & -f_j \cdot f_{kl} \\
& = & - f_{j} \cdot f_{lk} \\
& = & f_{jk} \cdot f_{l} \\
& = & f_{kj} \cdot f_{l} \\
& = & -f_{k} \cdot f_{lj} \\
& = & -f_k \cdot f_{jl} \\
\end{eqnarray}
$$
so that $f_{jl}\cdot f_k = 0$.  Note that I have swapped the order of differentiation (i.e. used Schwartz' theorem) numerous times above.  Now since $D_f(x)$ is an orthogonal matrix, the columns $f_i$ form an orthonormal basis for $\mathbb{R}^m$.  Since $f_{jk}$ is orthogonal to all $f_i$, it must therefore be the zero vector.  This shows that all second partials of $f$ vanish.

Comment: I'm lost with your notations (and mine when I tried to do it) but I agree

Comment: @user1952009 I edited just now to try to clarify the notation.  If you have specific points you want clarified, please let me know.